# Looking for an explanation of a line of code

Tags: vba

A bit new to vba and I had a buddy gave me this line:

ReDim Preserve InputD(1 To UBound(InputD, 1), 1 To 3)

I'm not fully sure what this line is doing, I understand the ReDim to change the values in the array and the preserve which keeps all data except the last. What exactly is the "To" statements doing inside this array? is it just specifying how many times to redim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `ReDim Preserve` acts different then `ReDim`. It is able **to modify only the last dimension** and preserve the (existing) values (if any). The way you use it is a little strange. I mean, normally it is good to `ReDim` an array to dimensions (especially the last one) able to cover the estimated number of elements to be loaded, plus something over. Usually, a variable being incremented with each new element added shell be used, in order to `Redim Preserve` at this specific variable number.

For instance:

```
Sub testRedimPreserve()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, arrToProcess, i As Long, k As Long
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range("A2:A20"): k = 1
 ReDim arrToProcess(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arr))  'redim at a maximum which surely will not be exceeded
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = "x" Then
        arrToProcess(1, k) = "Row " & i: arrToProcess(2, k) = "OK": k = k + 1
    End If
  Next i
  'Since some values in the range are not "x", the obtained array must use Redim Preserve:
  ReDim Preserve arrToProcess(1 To 2, 1 To k - 1) 'All the elements value up to k -1 are kept/preserved
  'Since only the last dimension can be preserved, the obtained array must be trasnposed.
  sh.Range("C2").Resize(k - 1, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrToProcess)
End Sub
```

1.a Of course, if you have a bigger array and you need only its first three columns, you can proceed like your friend suggested.

2. `Redim arr(1 to x)` means that the first element of the dimension is 1. In such a case it will keep elements from 1 to x. If not specify in this way, I mean `ReDim arr(x)`, the first element is zero. This is the default VBA. It works in 0 base. Except the case when `Option Base 1` is used on top of the module...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [ReDim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) you will see *subscripts* in the parenthesis and if you look further down you will see an explanation of subscripts:

> Required. Dimensions of an array variable; up to 60 multiple dimensions may be declared. The subscripts argument uses the following syntax:
>
> [ lowerTo ] upper [ , [ lowerTo ] upper ] . . .
>
> When not explicitly stated in lower, the lower bound of an array is controlled by the Option Base statement. The lower bound is zero if no Option Base statement is present.

What this means is that you resize your array `InputID` from whatever it was before to (from 1 to its upper bounds from before) for the first dimension and (from 1 to 3) for the second dimension.

Comment: I’m unsure what you’re getting at @FaneDuru the documentation mentions everything you said and the question was explicitly about the subscripts. If one doesn’t know the bounds of the first dimensions it is useful to check the bounds when resizing an array

Comment: I comment on your answer by mistake. I thought I am commenting on the OP question... Then, I thought that maybe will be good to place a more detailed answer, relevant to better understand the `ReDim Preserve` meaning...

Comment: Just a little more clarification from both of you, this line is changing my array's physical size from 1 to upperbounds in the 1st dimension and from 1 to 3 in the second? Simplified I guess as from a 1x1 array to a ((until data runs out) x 3) array.

Comment: @TrustedHippo: 1. When you want addressing to me when I placed an answer, please comment on my answer. In this way, no need to tag me. 2. No, it does  not change anything in the first dimension. **It is not possible**! This means that the first dimension is kept as it was and the second one it is set to 3. If your array has more then 3 columns this mean that after `Redim Preserve` it will have the same number of rows, but only three columns. From 1 to 3. If instead of `1 To 3` you would have only `3' the remained columns will be 4. From 0 to 3.

Comment: @TrustedHippo: 3. We here, when somebody spends some time in order to answer our question and we consider the answer "wonderful/useful etc.", we tick the left code side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the answer solved your problem...